# How to get a node with similar / identical relations?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say we have some data like this:

```
create
(a:Person{name:'andy'})-[:LIKES]->(:Animal{name:'cat'}),
(b:Person{name:'bob'})-[:LIKES]->(:Animal{name:'cat'}),
(c:Person{name:'charlie'})-[:LIKES]->(:Animal{name:'cat'}),
(a)-[:LIKES]->(:Animal{name:'dog'}),
(b)-[:LIKES]->(:Animal{name:'dog'})
```

I would like to know which Person has identical LIKES as andy. 
Andy likes 'cat' and 'dog', so Bob should appear, but not Charlie because he doesn't like 'dog'.

How can I form such query?
i'd like the query to work with many LIKES, so in the future when there are 100 animals, I can still find someone with identical taste as andy.

I've tried something like this

```
match
(p:Person{name:'andy'})-[:LIKES]->(a:Animal),
(a)<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)
return p,a,p2
```

But this would return Charlie as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find someone with exactly the same taste, you can use this query :

```
MATCH (p:Person{name:'andy'})-[:LIKES]->(a:Animal)
WITH collect(a) AS likes
MATCH (p2:Person)
WHERE all(n IN likes WHERE exists((p2)-[:LIKES]->(n)))
RETURN p2, likes
```